# How to find the complexity of while loop and recursive algorithms?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, while-loop, time-complexity

I am trying to determine how the complexity of an given algorithm grows with N.

```
1.
float epsilon = 0.001;
int a = 0;
int b = N - 1;
while (b - a > epsilon)
{
    int m = (int)((b + a) / 2);
    if (arr[m] > 0)
        b = m;
    else
        a = m;
}

2.
void f(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        printf("Hello\n");
    else
    {
        f(n - 1);
        f(n - 1);
    }
}
f(N);
```

For the first one, i think it will be o(n) = N , but i am not sure.

**Could someone explain how to find complexity of first and second algorithm?**

Comment: First one: O(∞) for the worst case (for example, `N = 2, arr[] = {0, 0}`)

Comment: Ignoring edge cases, it should be ```O(logN)``` and ```O(2^N)``` respectively

Comment: Can you explain pls , how you find answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First algorithm:**

As written, it makes little sense that `a`, `b` be `int`s and not `float`s, and I'll assume the latter. Also `N` instead of `N-1`.

Observe that on every iteration, the distance between `a` and `b` is halved, as long as it exceeds `epsilon`. Hence the number of iterations is `ceiling(lg(N/epsilon))`, the time it takes to reduce from `N` to less than `epsilon`.

Comment: thank you, got it. But what about second algorithm? Maybe i should put f(1),f(2),f(3) and then deduce the complexity ?

Comment: @Jordan: simulate execution by hand with `n=4`.